# Equation of cone using sphere and vertex outside sphere

Tags: algebraic-geometry

**Given equation of sphere and a vertex (v) outside sphere,find equation of cone touching the sphere with vertex (v).**
note:equation of sphere and vertex is in terms of x,y,z.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. I'm voting to close this question because you show no work of your own. Edit the question to tell us what you tried and where  you are stuck and perhaps we can help.

Answer (score 3):

Given a sphere $S$ with center at $p_0$ and radius $r$ and a point $p_1$ as vertex outside the sphere, the cone touching the sphere can be obtained using a pencil of lines passing by $p_1$ and tangent to $S$ so

$$
S\to ||p-p_0|| = r\\
L\to p = p_1 + \lambda \vec v
$$

where $p = (x,y,z)$

are the elements. Now $S \cap L $ gives

$$
||p_1-p_0+\lambda \vec v||^2=r^2
$$

or

$$
||p_1-p_0||^2+2\lambda < p_1-p_0,\vec v > + \lambda^2||\vec v||^2 = r^2
$$

now solving for $\lambda$

$$
\lambda = \frac{-2<p_1-p_0,\vec v > \pm \sqrt{4<p_1-p_0,\vec v>^2-4||\vec v||^2(||p_1-p_0||^2-r^2)}}{2||\vec v ||^2}
$$

but the lines should be tangent hence

$$
4<p_1-p_0,\vec v>^2-4||\vec v||^2(||p_1-p_0||^2-r^2)=0
$$

This is the cone parameterized by $\vec v$. Putting $\vec v = p-p_1$ we obtain the cone equation.

As an example, assuming

$$
p_0 = (0,0,0)\\
p_1 = (5,5,5)\\
r = 2
$$

we have the cone

$$
23 x^2-25 x y-25 x z+20 x+23 y^2-25 y z+20 y+23 z^2+20 z-150 = 0
$$

[image]

Comment: Really thanks sir,but i have a doubt here does <p1 - p0,v>means dot product right,could u recommend some article for this topic.

Comment: Yes. It is the representation of scalar product of two vectors. $< \vec u, \vec v >$

Comment: Sir could u please recommend any good book for geometry,as i do not have much knowledge of geometry

Comment: There are some books that you can download from the web. Try `Analytical Solid Geometry`